# How to find mouse position on click in GTK window using Perl?

Tags: perl, gtk

In my GTK+ application, I want to show an image and let the user click on it to draw lines. I'm doing this by generating a new image, with lines, with ImageMagick. This is my problem: How can I find out where the user clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to find coordinates of **click**, because that signal does not have them. You have to use the `button-press-event` and `button-release-event` signals. Than the second argument to the callback is GdkEventButton object and that has coordinates.

You may want to see the example for the GtkDrawingArea widget, it does just that.

Comment: Thanks for the hint on GtkDrawingArea!